# Cluster Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

We have done KMeans clustering with k=3 Clusters on dataset having 4 features, and have plotted the Centroid coordinates of each cluster with the input features. We want to focus on a cluster and try to figure out which feature is contributing more to a particular cluster with respect to other features. We do the same for other clusters too.

For e.g. lets assume we have clusters `c1` `c2` `c3` with features `f1` `f2` `f3` and `f4`. The centroids for the clusters are for e.g. 
`C1` `C2` `C3` respectively with corresponding features `f1` `f2` `f3` `f4`

```
         f1           f2         f3          f4
 C1 -2.02746249  2.10961828 -0.57917217  1.687631

 C2  0.63967987 -0.55768793  0.76387423  0.265274

 C3 -0.38727624  0.18714381 -1.27291271 -1.273105
```

Can we infer that for cluster 1 since the centroid for `f2` (feature2) is highest so can that be considered as the most significant/contributing feature for that particular cluster, similarly for cluster 2 centroid for `f3`(feature3) is highest so can that be considered as the important feature for cluster 2.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (if you decide to move it yourself, please delete this one, as [cross-posting in not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)).

Comment: Cross-posted duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/398499/7828